# Terraform Invalid for_each argument local will be known only after apply

Tags: terraform

I would like to create an AWS account with SSO Account Assignments in the same first terraform run without hit the **for_each** limitation with dynamic values that cannot be predicted during plan.

I've tried to separate the **aws_organizations_account** resource from **aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment** in completely separate TF module and also I tried to use depends_on between those resources and modules.

What is the simplest and correct way to fix this issue?

**Terraform v1.2.4**

[AWS SSO Account Assignments Module](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-sso/tree/master/modules/account-assignments)

[Closed Pull Request that did not fix this issue](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-sso/pull/19#issuecomment-901274639)

[image]

**main.tf file (aws module)**

```
resource "aws_organizations_account" "account" {
  name  = var.aws_account_name
  email = "${var.aws_account_name}@gmail.com"

  tags = {
    Name  = var.aws_account_name
  }

  parent_id = var.aws_org_folder_id
}

data "aws_identitystore_group" "this" {
  for_each          = local.group_list
  identity_store_id = local.identity_store_id

  filter {
    attribute_path  = "DisplayName"
    attribute_value = each.key
  }
}

data "aws_identitystore_user" "this" {
  for_each          = local.user_list
  identity_store_id = local.identity_store_id

  filter {
    attribute_path  = "UserName"
    attribute_value = each.key
  }
}

data "aws_ssoadmin_instances" "this" {}

locals {
  assignment_map = {
    for a in var.account_assignments :
    format("%v-%v-%v-%v", aws_organizations_account.account.id, substr(a.principal_type, 0, 1), a.principal_name, a.permission_set_name) => a
  }

  identity_store_id = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.this.identity_store_ids)[0]
  sso_instance_arn  = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.this.arns)[0]

  group_list = toset([for mapping in var.account_assignments : mapping.principal_name if mapping.principal_type == "GROUP"])
  user_list  = toset([for mapping in var.account_assignments : mapping.principal_name if mapping.principal_type == "USER"])
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "this" {
  for_each = local.assignment_map

  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
  permission_set_arn = each.value.permission_set_arn

  principal_id   = each.value.principal_type == "GROUP" ? data.aws_identitystore_group.this[each.value.principal_name].id : data.aws_identitystore_user.this[each.value.principal_name].id
  principal_type = each.value.principal_type

  target_id   = aws_organizations_account.account.id
  target_type = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
}
```

**main.tf (root)**

```
module "sso_account_assignments" {
    source = "./modules/aws"

  account_assignments = [
    {
        permission_set_arn = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-31d20e5987f0ce66",
        permission_set_name = "ReadOnlyAccess",
        principal_type = "GROUP",
        principal_name = "Administrators"
    },
    {
        permission_set_arn = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-955c264e8f20fea3",
        permission_set_name = "ReadOnlyAccess",
        principal_type = "GROUP",
        principal_name = "Developers"
    },
    {
        permission_set_arn = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-31d20e5987f0ce66",
        permission_set_name = "ReadOnlyAccess",
        principal_type = "GROUP",
        principal_name = "Developers"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: So, local are evaluated before anything else, so that means you cannot use the resource that will be created in a local variable which should be used in another `for_each`. However, I think you could use the expression from the local variable in the `for_each` directly and it **should** work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing about a map for `for_each` is that all of the keys must be made only of values that Terraform can "see" during the planning step.

You defined `local.assignment_map` this way in your example:

```
  assignment_map = {
    for a in var.account_assignments :
    format("%v-%v-%v-%v", aws_organizations_account.account.id, substr(a.principal_type, 0, 1), a.principal_name, a.permission_set_name) => a
  }
```

I'm not personally familiar with the `aws_organizations_account` resource type, but I'm guessing that `aws_organizations_account.account.id` is an attribute whose value gets decided by the remote system during the apply step (once the object is created) and so this isn't a suitable value to use as part of a `for_each` map key.

If so, I think the best path forward here is to use a different attribute of the resource that is defined statically in your configuration. If `var.aws_account_name` has a static value defined in your configuration (that is, it isn't derived from an apply-time attribute of another resource) then it might work to use the `name` attribute instead of the `id` attribute:

```
  assignment_map = {
    for a in var.account_assignments :
    format("%v-%v-%v-%v", aws_organizations_account.account.name, substr(a.principal_type, 0, 1), a.principal_name, a.permission_set_name) => a
  }
```

Another option would be to remove the organization reference from the key altogether. From what you've shared it seems like there is only one account and so all of these keys would end up starting with exactly the same account name anyway, and so that string isn't contributing to the uniqueness of those keys. If that's true then you could drop that part of the key and just keep the other parts as the unique key:

```
  assignment_map = {
    for a in var.account_assignments :
    format(
      "%v-%v-%v",
      substr(a.principal_type, 0, 1),
      a.principal_name,
      a.permission_set_name,
    ) => a
  }
```